# How can an ensemble perform worse than all but one of its constituents?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

I came across a very unusual situation:

1. I trained 5 deep nets on a problem.
2. 4 of the 5 had excellent in- and out-of-sample accuracy.
3. I trained a classifier on the probability outputs of the 5 deep nets to predict the label. (I tried XGBoost, linear methods, random forests, and even random kitchen sinks.)

The final classifier performs worse than the 4 "good" base classifiers. Even when I remove the one "bad" base classifier, the final ensemble still performs worse than any individual base classifier.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

EDIT: the final ensemble's in-sample accuracy is 100%. I think this is clearly a problem of overfitting, but it seems odd it could actually perform *worse*. I wonder if data augmentation would get me anywhere?

EDIT2: Using SMOTE to generate new samples of my 5-dimension vectors right before the last step got some lift, but it still isn't on par with the original base classifiers.

Comment: 1. to eliminating the overfitting concern, try a simple ensemble (e.g average for regression and majority vote for classification) - it should perform better than the ind. nets. 2. if you are keen on learning an ensemble, make sure to do it on a fresh hold out (i.e do not reuse your training data).